# Package by feature modularization in Java

Tags: java, module, architecture, domain-driven-design

I've got an application with package by layer layout written in Spring and exposing REST API, so I've got packages called controller, service, model, dao etc.

I want to refactor it, so it will be package by feature, where every top-level package will be little module with a facade class (which will be public), and package-private controller, service, repository classes. Just to make sure that everything is small and organized.

Separating them by feature is not a problem, but what should I do with entities?

I've got a structure of model like this:

[image: model]

For example: I've got a feature that handles adding, removing etc. of auditorAssignment objects. So in new package there will be rest controller exposing such API, service, repository (all package-private) and some public facade that another modules could use (i.e. to get assignments or add them if needed). What should I do with whole model - entities? Should it be placed somewhere outside as a core? Or maybe entities should be splitted between packages, but public (to get relationships working)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should package by [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) (`BC`) and not by `feature` (considering that a `BC` can have one or more `features`). Then you can use any of the [integration technics](http://culttt.com/2014/11/26/strategies-integrating-bounded-contexts/) between `BC`, for example `anti-corruption layers`.

> What should I do with whole model - entities? Should it be placed somewhere outside as a core? Or maybe entities should be splitted between packages, but public (to get relationships working)?

In case of entities you split them by the attributes specific in every `BC` and they can share the same `IDs` so you can update the shared proporties also (as there are a lot of cases where entities in different `BC` have some common properties; i.e. `nickname` for users in the `Authorization BC` and `Author name` for the corresponding author in the `Colaboration BC`).

P.S. If you split them like that you are at an inch distance from microservices

Comment: I understand this concept, but It's not a big project and I didn't want to use bounded context in such strict matter now. For now, after first part implemented I wanted to make refactoring, splitting it into modules by feature and prepare them for further grow. Eventually after they expand it will be possible to transform them into bounded contexts with own model easily, since this isn't in production yet. What do you think about such approach?

Comment: It is good in general to group things that work together, it is said to have `high cohesion` but if you talk about DDD then my answer is a must.

Comment: Thank you, now I know everything. For now I will use public entities, but when I will introduce new bigger feature then it will be bounded context.